# Group by Linq setting properties

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a `groupby` query using Linq, but I want to set the value for a new property in combination with another list. This is my code:

```
var result = list1.GroupBy(f => f.Name)
                  .ToList()
                  .Select(b => new Obj
                  {
                      ClientName = b.Name,
                      Status = (AnotherClass.List().Where(a=>a.state_id=b.????).First()).Status
                  })
```

I know I'm using a `group by`, but I'm not sure of how to access the value inside my `b`collection to compare it with `a.state_id`.
This snippet:

```
Status = (AnotherClass.List().Where(a=>a.state_id=b.????).First()).Status
```

I've done that before but months ago I don't remember the syntax, when I put a dot behind `b` I have acces only to `Key` and the Linq Methods... What should be the syntax?`

Comment: *"I have acces only to Key and the Linq Methods"*, `b.Value`?

Comment: A. What exactly do you want to do with it. You group by name but then it seems like you want to search by status. Please provid some sample data with input and expected output
B. IF you already did it before then why post a question and not find the answer online

Comment: @MattBurland In that case, `b` is the collection of all the objects within the Group. There is no `b.Value` property available.

Comment: hi guys I think I found the way it was very simple but I wasn't able to remember:   `Status = (RiPSCached.Status().Where(r => r.aut_id == b.Select(a => a.int_statusId).First()).First()).txt_status`

Comment: b contains an IGrouping element consisting of two properties: .Key -> the name it was groupedBy and .Count -> The number of elements sharing this name

Comment: I've changed the names of the fields in my question sorry, but the syntax is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in your code is happening here:

`a=>a.state_id=b.????`

**Why ?**

Check type of `b` here, it would be `IGrouping<TKey,TValue>`, which is because, post `GroupBy` on an `IEnumerable`, you get result as `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TValue>>`

**What does that mean?**

Think of Grouping operation in the database, where when you `GroupBy` on a given `Key`, then remaining columns that are selected need an aggregation operation,since there could be more than one record per key and that needs to be represented

**How it is represented in your code**

1. Let's assume `list1` has `Type T` objects
2. You grouped the data by `Name property`, which is part of `Type T`
3. There's no data projection so for a given key, it will aggregate the remaining data as `IEnumerable<T>`, as grouped values
4. Result is in the format `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TK, TV>>`, where `TK` is Name and TV represent `IEnumerable<T>`

Let's check out some code, break your original code in following parts

- `var result = list1.GroupBy(f => f.Name)`  - `result` will be of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,T>>`, where `list1` is `IEnumerable<T>`
- On doing `result.Select(b => ...)`, `b` is of type `IGrouping<string,T>`
- Further you can run Linq queries on `b`, as follows:
  `b.Key`, will give access to `Name` Key, there's no `b.Value`, for that your options could be following or any other relevant Linq operations:

`a=>b.Any(x => a.state_id == x.state_id)` or // Suuggests if an Id match in the Collection
`a=>a.state_id == b.FirstOrDefault(x => x.state_id)` //Selects First or default Value

Thus you can create a final result, from the `IGrouping<string,T>`, as per the logical requirement / use case